# Weka stringtowordvector error

Tags: weka

trying use the stringtowordvector filter on weka 3.6.8. I selected the filter, left the defaults in place, and indicated the attribute to be converted. I get the error "Problem filtering instances: 33"

Has anyone come across this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Weka's Explorer? Also, could you add a sample of your .arff file?

Comment: o.k. it seems that that the parameter DoNotOperateOnPerClassBasis had to be changed. The default is False, but setting it to True resolved the error. Thanks!!

Comment: Good to hear; On Stack Overflow it is [OK to answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), so could you add your answer as a answer post and accept it (by [ticking the checkmark](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to the left of your answer)? This way the community can easily see that the question is answered and solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user1038067 said that: It seems that that the parameter DoNotOperateOnPerClassBasis had to be changed. The default is False, but setting it to True resolved the error